# Lyx: problem with included graphics path

Tags: lyx, ubuntu

I recently installed Lyx in a fresh install of Xubuntu 18.04 and am experiencing some problems with included graphics. It seems that the path to the file is not being properly passed to Inkscape when creating the PDF file. Let me illustrate with an example.

I have a Lyx file located at "/home/me/Dropbox/FCEN/Astrofisica/Mis cosas/Formulas/". This file includes an SVG graphic that is called "1.svg" and is located in the same place. So in Lyx I have

[image]

This works perfectly in my personal computer (also with Xubuntu 18.04 and the same version of Lyx), when I hit export PDF it proceeds straightforward. However, in this new fresh Xubuntu installation I get the following message when I hit export PDF:

[image]

As can be seen Lyx believes that the path to the file is `7_home_me_Dropbox_FCEN_Astrofisica_Mis_cosas_Formulas_1.svg` whereas it should be `/home/me/Dropbox/FCEN/Astrofisica/Mis cosas/Formulas/1.svg`

After this message is shown for each graphic that has been included, the PDF is exported but in place of the graphics there is a blank square with this inscription "7_home_me_Dropbox_FCEN_Astrofisica_Mis_cosas_Formulas_1.svg"

---

EDIT:

The guilty seems not to be Lyx but Inkscape or Ubuntu. I have checked that if I export the SVG image to PDF and then include it into Lyx, everything works ok. Also, if I try to open the SVG file with "right click → open with Inkscape" something strange happens too:

[image]

There is an issue with blank spaces in this case. I don't know if this problem has to do with Inkscape (I have the last version), with Ubuntu, or both.

Comment: Just to help debug, if you convert your svg file to a pdf file, do things work correctly?

Comment: Yes, in that case it works all right. Maybe it is a problem with Inkscape. I will check that and comment again.

Comment: To check that, just try another svg file that you can open and see that is ok.

Comment: I have the same problem. I mean, if I delete the blank space in "New Folder" in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMnyD.png) then "right clik→open with Inkscape" works ok but I get the same strange pahts with the '/' replaced by '_'.

Comment: You could try using rsvg-convert, instead of inkscape to do the conversion of svg files. Read Help > Customization about converters.

Comment: Lyx works with temporal files in `/tmp`/ directory. What show the error message is only the file name of the temporal file.  Probably the conversion error is caused by the spaces in the source path. Try renaming the folder  "Mis cosas" to "MisCosas", "New folder" to "NewFOlder and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost accidentally I found the solution. I let it here for future reference:

[image]